# Open colorbox when click on an image within openlayer ballon (popup)

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox, openlayers

I can open colorbox when click on an image from within openlayer balloon (popup). The problem is that it work only one time. After I reload the page it work again but only one time.

When I look at chrome console I get this error:

"Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'colorbox".

The code into an external .js file is:

```
function call_colorbox(url) {
jQuery.colorbox({href: url, height: "80%", width: "80%"});
};
```

the code within the openlayer baloon (popup) is:

```
<a href="#" onClick="call_colorbox('/mypage.html')"><img src="myimg.jpg" alt="title"  title="title" /></a>
```

Can somebody give me an hint how to correct the problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid inline script handlers. Choose an identifier which you can target in your javascript, for example `.colorbox`:

```
<a href="#" class="colorbox" data-url="example.html"> .. </a>
```

Then in your JS (assuming you load the jQuery library):

```
$('body').on('click', '.colorbox', function (event) {
  $.colorbox({href: $(this).data('url'), height: "80%", width: "80%"});
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I tried your code. If I put the link in a body of an html page is working fine. But when the link is located inside a popup generated from a javascript (openlayer) the code you sent me cannot find the identifier class ".colorbox".

Comment: With the code you provided I cannot help you with openlayer. Could you provide the openlayer javascript you use to generate/trigger the popup?